# I can't translate the info.plist strings

Tags: string, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, translation, info.plist

[image]

I have this structure and all the files have this content, but it doesn't translate the texts of the alerts of the permissions

Localizable.strings (content - es):

```
"NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" = "Esta aplicación necesita acceso a las fotos. Para poder guardar la nueva foto tomada por la cámara.";

"NSCameraUsageDescription" = "Esta aplicación necesita acceso a la cámara para poder tomar una nueva foto.";

"NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription" = "Esta aplicación necesita acceso a la galería de fotos, para poder seleccionar...";
```

InfoPlist.strings (content - en):

```
 "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" = "This application needs access to photos. In order to save the new photo taken by the camera.";

"NSCameraUsageDescription" = "This application needs access to the camera in order to take a new picture.";

"NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription" = "This application needs access to the photo gallery, to be able to select a new photo
```

Also I have this in the Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
        <string>es</string>
        <string>en</string>
    </array>

<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
  <string>es</string>
```

And

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Esta aplicación necesita acceso a las fotos. Para poder guardar la nueva foto tomada por la cámara.</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Esta aplicación necesita acceso a la cámara para poder tomar una nueva foto.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Esta aplicación necesita acceso a la galería de fotos, para poder seleccionar una nueva foto y poder utilizarla en la app.</string>
```

But it doesn't work, I think that it is rare, because I have the CFBundleDevelopmentRegion (es) and the alerts title are in english, the language of the mobile, and the text in spanish

[image]

Strings don't change of language, but the titles yes

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the .Iproj, I was putting .Iproj (capital letter "i") instead of .lproj (lowercase letter "L")

And also, I had to put into the info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations</key>
  <true/>
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer , which will help more people :)

Comment: Adding CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations solves it for me, but it seems like it shouldn't? The description of CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations suggests it is used for frameworks.